# How is correlation done between identified PCA components?

Tags: correlation, pca, dimensionality-reduction, likert, factor-rotation

I am very new to statistics on this level (PCA, Correlations etc.). I am currently writing a paper and following the methodology from another journal paper. In the journal paper a PCA is done on a set of Likert scale questions (1-5) with number of factors set to 5.

Now the next step in the journal paper - after identifying the factors/components - is they have done a correlation (the table's name in the paper is Pearson bivariate correlation analysis) on the factors/components.

My question is how were the identified components/factors merged to have the correlation done on them? Was the mean of each of the questions making up the factors/components used to create a new variable?

This image might help explain my question better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAhlC.jpg

I'm not sure if the answer is very obvious/simple that I am missing but I have looked and searched everywhere I just can't find anything on it. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I don't know the reference, but I think that the authors have carried a PCA with an oblique rotation which permits correlations between factors, and thus, they are reporting the results. To get a similar result, you need to add an oblique rotation after PCA. Without that, PCA dimensions are orthogonal, e.g., uncorrelated to each others.

---

EDIT

From the comments below, the authors used an orthogonal rotation on 5 dimensions. If you wan to do exactly the same, use PCA, retains 5 dimensions and add a varimax rotation. Most softwares will let you record scores for each participant on every factors. Finally, carry out a correlation analysis on these extracted factors. You will have replicate this part of the analysis.

I will leave this as an open comment, but I find this approach questionable. The correlations between factors are induced by the rotation. So variance that were not related to the original components (a kind of errors) are added to the rotated components. At best the the correlation matrix between rotated components only tells you informations on the rotation itself. At worst, they are commenting on "opportunistic" error (from optimizing loadings).

Comment: +1 to POC. PCAs are uncorrelated. I'd need to see the whole paper, but this is a very strange methodology. Unless this is standard practice in your field, I don't know how closely I'd follow it.

Comment: Here's the PDF https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bvWJpxjsQDVwJ3P919d9P-AzlX2l2euZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: While searching for the link to their study for the above commenters' reference and before uploading to Google Drive I found another of the authors similar study in which they mention taking the weighted mean of the factors. Adding the quote in the next comment from the study found here (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262966357_Barriers_to_small_business_growth_in_Canada)

Comment: "The question subsets were analysed in order to enable the calculation of the weighted
factor scores. In terms of these weighted factor score items: three lack of capital, three
lack of skills, two perception on capital losses, two lack of confidence, three compliant
costs, and the two individual intention to start-up a small business, loaded approximately equally"

Comment: Following the note on weighted mean (as quoted above) in the latter study linked above, a Regression coefficients table is presented showing the relationship between the identified PCA components. So I assume that once factors are identified, a new column in added for the factors such as F1,F2...Fn which hold the weighted mean of the identified set items and then proceed with correlation or regression on F1,F2,...Fn to identify relationships or correlations between the factors? Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks POC for the input. This is too conflicting. I am thinking of following the approach in this study(linked below). I will perform a PCA and then on the identified items making up the factors/components I will take their weighted mean and perform the One-way ANOVA as the author has done (page 269). Is my understanding correct on this procedure? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_cYOzi6opAOR4XgfTuVpWCpeT_6MucME/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your grouping variable for anova?

Comment: The weighted means of the identified factors by PCA, as it's done in the study linked above.